# insert to a pointer to std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, stdmap

I'm using a `map` inside a `map`:

```
std::map<int, std::map<DWORD,IDLL::CClass*>*> *MyMap
```

I'm using the following code to insert into the `map`:

```
std::map<DWORD,IDLL::CClass*> *SecondMap;
SecondMap= new std::map<DWORD,IDLL::CClass*>; 
DWORD i = 1;
while (eteration on obj type IDLL::CClass ) 
{
     SecondMap.insert(std::make_pair(i,&obj));           
}int j = 1;    


MyMap->insert(std::make_pair(1,&SecondMap));
```

Later in the programm the `map` has become empty!

Could any one help please?

Comment: What is the reason *not* to use `std::map<int, std::map<DWORD,IDLL::CClass> > MyMap` (without the pointers)?

Comment: @ipc, when the value object does not allow for copying?

Comment: I have to use many maps so I choose poniters to decrease the memory use

Comment: @user2161341: unless there are mulitple pointers to common maps, using pointers will *increase* the memory use.  Since it looks like you create a new map for every pointer, there will be no common maps.

Comment: And even then, you can reduce memory usage with `shared_ptr` because I guess you have memory leaks.

Comment: @Chris could you explain more please ?

Comment: @user2161341: Using pointers means you need space for the pointers as well as space for the maps.  Unless you have multiple pointers pointing at the same map (which requires additional bookkeeping to keep track of when all the pointers go away, such as `std::shared_ptr`), you're almost always better off not using pointers.

Comment: Most likely problem is that the `IDLL::CClass` pointers you are creating with `&obj` become dangling at the end of each iteration of the while loop (as `obj` is local to the loop), so the map isn't actually empty, its just that all the pointers in it are invalid.  But as the code you've posted is not an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), I'm only guessing.

Comment: 1) Did you remember to create the map (e.g. `MyMap = new ...`)? 2)Is the map empty *immediately* after the insertion? 3) You seem to be inexperienced with pointers; you should not use them for memory conservation (or any purpose really) until you understand them better.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: A map containing invalid pointers is not empty. I suspect that this particular problem is in code we haven't seen, and that there are other serious bugs as well.

Comment: `std::map<std::pair<int, DWORD>,IDLL::CClass*> my_map` may work better for you. You can simple combine the two keys with a `std::pair`, and stop using pointers while your at it. Containers do not generally need to be declared on the heap.

Comment: Note that you have a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363505/nested-stdmap-using-pointers).

Answer (score 2):

Having ***owning*** raw pointers is a bad practice in general (unless you are in special cases, like if you are building a custom advanced data structures, and the owning raw pointers are protected in proper RAII class boundaries).

The first option should be to use value semantics; if that is not good for your performance, then you may want to use **smart pointers** like `shared_ptr` (this helps make your code simpler, make it exception-safe, avoid resource leaks, etc.).

This is a sample compilable code, that seems to work on VS2010 SP1 (VC10):

```
#include <iostream>     // for std::cout
#include <map>          // for std::map
#include <memory>       // for std::shared_ptr and std::make_shared
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int DWORD;    

struct MyClass
{
    MyClass() : Data(0) {}
    explicit MyClass(int data) : Data(data) {}

    int Data;
};

int main()
{
    //
    // Build some test maps
    //

    typedef map<DWORD, shared_ptr<MyClass>> InnerMap;
    typedef map<int, shared_ptr<InnerMap>> OuterMap;

    auto innerMap1 = make_shared<InnerMap>();
    (*innerMap1)[10] = make_shared<MyClass>(10);
    (*innerMap1)[20] = make_shared<MyClass>(20);

    OuterMap myMap;

    myMap[30] = innerMap1;


    //
    // Testing code for maps access
    //

    const int keyOuter = 30;
    auto itOuter = myMap.find(keyOuter);
    if (itOuter != myMap.end())
    {
        // Key present in outer map.
        // Repeat find in inner map.

        auto innerMapPtr = itOuter->second;
        const DWORD keyInner = 20;
        auto itInner = innerMapPtr->find(keyInner);
        if (itInner !=  innerMapPtr->end())
        {
            cout << itInner->second->Data << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```